# How to convert JSON data when forwarding another controller to array in symfony2?

Tags: json, symfony, forward

In one of my action I use forwarding to get data from other controller:

```
$collect = ($this ->forward('MyPracticeBundle:Collect:collect', array('jid' => 1, 'rid' => $rid)));
```

The collectAction in CollectController would return an json response:

```
return new response(json_encode(array("havecollect" => 0)));
```

And now I want to get those data from other controller, I tried:

```
$collect = json_decode($collect);
```

But that won't work, What should I do to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `->getContent()`behind my response, and use `$collect = json_decode($collect, true);` instead, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not getting JSON as a result from `forward` method but symfony response object.  Furthermore, guessing from your code snippets, you're trying to do a **very bad** thing.

If you want one action to collect data and return it in JSON format while other does something else to that data, you should make a **method in your service layer** which retrieves that data and use it in both actions.

Comment: First of all, I am just learning, and it is not bad at all. As for response object, there is a method "getContent()" which could return what a response contains. But I still can't get JSON from the Content...

Comment: I just find a way to get it. Just add '->getContent()' behind my response, and set the second parameter as 'true' in my json_decode function. Any way, thanks for answering...